# Why is the hypercube also called the "measure polytope"?

Tags: terminology, polytopes

The title expresses my question.
Wikipedia says [the term was originated by Elte in 1912](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube), and Coxeter later
adopted the term
in his book *Regular Polytopes*, using the symbol $\gamma_n$ for the $n$-cube [p.123].
But why "measure"?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Thanks! I should have read to the bottom of the page. :-)